# Stop product options from displaying in the minicart

Tags: magento2, template, html, knockoutjs, mini-cart

How do I stop product options from displaying in the minicart?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this can be done via JS and via HTML templates, this is the template method.

Copy the below file into your theme and remove the code shown.

```
File: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html:34

...

<!-- ko if: options.length -->
<div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
    <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

    <div data-role="content" class="content">
        <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
        <dl class="product options list">
            <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
            <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
            <dd class="values">
                <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                    <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                    <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </dd>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->

...
```

You will likely need to clear browser cache after you deploy, and possibly compile/deploy static assets depending on your workflow.

Comment: Can you please give me js path for get options array value?